# Subtract value from a List in Java

Tags: java, arrays, list

This is my code:

```java
public void tick {
    for (Integer i : list) {
        list.add(i-1);
        list.remove(i); 
        System.out.println(list);  
    }
}
```

I have a list of "x" elements (int values). On every "tick" I want to deduct `-1` from the entire array without making any position shifts. My approach leads to shifting.

Comment: please try to ask your question in correct english syntax

Comment: you are changing  `list` while iterating through it. This can cause quite ugly `ConcurrentModificationException`s and should be avoided.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]

Comment: And please please please: details matter: an ARRAY is NOT a LIST. You seem to be using ArrayList - that has NOTHING to do with arrays!

Comment: Finally: you want to be really careful about the AUTO boxing and unboxing that takes place in your code. The compiler is turning Integer into int and back quickly, and **you** should understand when that happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list.remove()` throws [ConcurrentModificationException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) if you are removing elements while iterating it.

So, you need to use [list.set()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) **to set the value at an index while iterating the list** as shown in the below code (follow the comments):

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
   int val = list.get(i);//get the value
   list.set(i, (val-1));//subtract and set the value at the same index
}
```

Comment: Note that using a `ListIterator` is better than using index-based `get` and `set` (at least where you've got a non-random access list like `LinkedList`).

Answer (score 1):

Integers are immutable, but if java8 then  you can invoke the method `replaceAll`, doc [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-)

```
List<Integer> l = Arrays.asList(2, 4, 6, 8, 10);
System.out.println(l);
l.replaceAll(x -> --x);
System.out.println(l);
```

Comment: I think you should be careful throwing lambdas at a total newbie.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to use list, you can use int array and for loop like:

```
int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4};
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
     a[i] -= 1;
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
```

output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Whats the advantage of using a fixed size array over lists? Why not fix the problem he has with his lists, instead of suggesting something completely different?!

Comment: @GhostCat he mentioned array in his question and I thought arrays are more newbie friendly